# onSaveInstanceState didn't call writeToParcel

Tags: android, android-view

I'm trying to create a custom view that will save it's state. When I tried to rotate it, it called the onSaveInstanceState but never call the writeToParcel.

This is the onSaveInstanceState :

```
@Override
public Parcelable onSaveInstanceState()
{
    Logger.d("On Save Instance State");

    Parcelable superState = super.onSaveInstanceState();

    PictureItemState pis = new PictureItemState(superState);

    for (PictureItem item : mImageList)
    {
        if (!item.isButton)
        {
            pis.mUriList.add(item.uri.toString());
            pis.mIndexList.add(item.index);
        }
    }

    return pis;
}
```

and this is the state class that implement writeToParcel :

```
static class PictureItemState extends BaseSavedState
{
...    
@Override
    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags)
    {
        super.writeToParcel(dest, flags);

        Logger.d("Write to parcel");

        int size = mUriList.size();

        dest.writeInt(size);

        for (int i = 0; i < size; i++)
        {
            dest.writeString(mUriList.get(i));
            dest.writeInt(mIndexList.get(i));
        }
    }
...
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Android: Parcelable.writeToParcel and Parcelable.Creator.createFromParcel are never called](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853952/android-parcelable-writetoparcel-and-parcelable-creator-createfromparcel-are-ne)