# Object Reference when saving / retrieving parcelable from a fragment's Arguments bundle

Tags: android, android-fragments

I have a StudentList fragment, which has a List; the Student class implements Parcelable; clicking an item in the StudentList fragment invokes the following StudentFragment:

```
public static StudentFragment newInstance(Student student_) {
    StudentFragment fragment = new StudentFragment();
    Bundle args = new Bundle();
    args.putParcelable("STUDENT", student_);
    fragment.setArguments(args);
    return fragment;
}

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    Bundle args = getArguments();
    if (args != null) {
        mStudent = args.getParcelable("STUDENT");
    }
}

private void setStudentName(String newName_) {
   mStudent.setName(newName_);
}
```

This fragment is instantiated from another "StudentList" fragment, which has a List; an object from his list is provided as the parameter to StudentFragment.newInstance().

I was surprised to see that any changes to mStudent in the "StudentFragment" automatically get reflected on the corresponding object. On checking further in the onCreate method of StudentFragment, I found that the mStudent object reference is the same as the reference of the object that was passed to newInstance.

When I stepped through the code, I found that the Student.writeToParcel is never called.

How is this possible? Shouldn't I get a NEW object reference when I call mStudent = args.getParcelable("STUDENT") ?

Does the "arguments" bundle or the Parcelable interface preserve some link to the object reference, and use the parcel/unparceling as a last resort?

Comment: if fragmnet is recreated then you can get to know that student parcalable object with prev state is retrieved with new reference

Comment: My question is, why am I getting the same object back after calling args.getParcelable("STUDENT"); I expect that this would return me a new object.

Comment: you can expect the new ref when activity is recreated on screen orienataion then marshaling and unmarshaling student objects is done

Answer (score 1):

[This post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4853952/android-parcelable-writetoparcel-and-parcelable-creator-createfromparcel-are-ne) states that there's no guarantee that writing/reading to/from a Bundle will cause parceling/unparceling. Moreover it states that one shouldn't assume either behavior. This is probably why I keep getting back the exact same reference in onCreate.